# read data from web service android

Tags: java, android, web-services

i have made web service with php Zend like this

```
<?php
 require('Zend\Db.php');
 require('Zend\Db\Exception.php');
 require('Zend\Debug.php');

 function sendResponse($status, $payload)
{
$responseCodeList = array(
    200 => 'OK',
    201 => 'Created',
    204 => 'No Content',
    301 => 'Moved Permanently',
    400 => 'Bad Request',
    404 => 'Not Found',
    410 => 'Gone',
    501 => 'Not Implemented',
);

header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . $responseCodeList[$status]);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo (string) $payload;
}

try {
     $db = Zend_Db::factory('Oracle', array(
       'host'       => '10.234.152.35',
       'username'   => 'REPORT',
       'password'   => 'r4pt0rsdw',
       'dbname'     => '//10.234.152.35/SATDW',
   ));
  } catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
echo sendResponse(200,'100|Database Error');
exit;
  }

  $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

  $payload = '';

  if ($method = 'GET') {
   $data = $_GET;
   //$sql = "select * from rpt_ms_dc where msd_code = :code";
   try {
       $select = $db->select()
                    ->from(
                       'RPT_MS_DC',
                       array(
                           'KODE' => 'MSD_CODE',
                           'NAMA' => 'MSD_DESC',
                       )
                    )
                    ->where('MSD_CODE = ?', $data['code']);
       $stmt = $select->query();
       $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
       //return $result;
       //$payload = $result[0]['KODE'].$result[0]['NAMA'];
       $payload = json_encode($result);
       //Zend_Debug::dump($result[0]['KODE'].'||'.$result[0]['NAMA']);exit;
      } catch(Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
          Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());exit;
      }
  }

echo sendResponse(200, $payload);
```

and the result like this :

> [{"KODE":"A","NAMA":"DC SERPONG"}]

then i want retrieve just **DC SERPONG** in my edit text
how can i do this??
this is my android code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    etKode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtKode);
    etNama = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBranch);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);

    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            // setiap parameter yang akan dikirim melalui http
            // harus encode agar
            // dapat terbaca dengan baik oleh server
            String kode = URLEncoder.encode(etKode.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
            //String nama = URLEncoder.encode(etNama.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
            url += "?code=" + kode ;
            getRequest(url);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
}
public void getRequest(String Url) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
                int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);
                if(timeoutConnection > 3000){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Request Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("Request Timeout");
                }
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Tambah Data " + request(response) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(res);
                etNama.setText(res);

        }

public static String request(HttpResponse response) {

            String result = "";
            try {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result = str.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                result = "Error";
            }

            return result;
        }
```